# load external website after embed youtube ends

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to prepare responsive landing page for mobiles where only embed video will be visible.

Problem is – **I am trying to redirect to another website when the movie will end.**

I am reading about yt API, but it is hard for me to grasp at the moment.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Need to target the players events. When it is finished playing, the event can target a script to load a new page.